# predicateForEventsWithStartDate:endDate:calendars: EKEventStore doesn't work

Tags: ios6, ekevent, ekeventstore

i have saved 28 EKEvent in a EKCalendar in this range date: 2012-01-01 and 2013-01-18, the EKEvent are all stored and i can see it in the iOS Calendar on iCloud, then i want retrieve all this EKEvent in the range 2012-01-01 and 2013-01-18 and i use this method of EKEventStore:

```
predicateForEventsWithStartDate:endDate:calendars:
```

that is a NSPredicate to fetch event in the calendar, i pass with start date 2012-01-01 and with endDate:2013-01-18 so the array that return me with the EKEvent have only 8 element, so my question is why it doesn't find me all 28 event? what i wrong?

EDIT:

this is the complete code i use:

```
NSDate* sourceDate2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2012/01/01"];


    NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone2 = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone2 = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    NSInteger sourceGMTOffset2 = [sourceTimeZone2 secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate2];
    NSInteger destinationGMTOffset2 = [destinationTimeZone2 secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate2];
    NSTimeInterval interval2 = destinationGMTOffset2 - sourceGMTOffset2;

    NSDate* destinationDate2 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval2 sinceDate:sourceDate2];

    NSTimeInterval time2 = floor([destinationDate2 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] / 86400.0) * 86400.0;

    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:time2];
```

then i use the same code for create the 2013-01-18 date that is the endDate, then i do this:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

NSPredicate *predicateEvent = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:[eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent]];

NSArray *eventArray = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicateEvent];
```

the eventArray contains only 8 elements...and where are the other 20? please i'm going crazy someone can help me?

Comment: are the 28 `EVEvent`s in the same `EKCalendar`? can you post the full code how you try to fetch your `EKEvent`s?

Comment: Yes are in the same calendar...

Comment: no don't work also if i save the event identifier and the retrieve the event with the identifier, return null..

Answer (score 2):

On your device, go to: `Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars`, and under the `Calendars` sub-section go to `Sync > All Events`. Not just events from the past 30, 60 days, etc.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i haven't tried if your solution works, but i have a question, if i release my app on app store, i can't go on every user device and change that option :)