# How set no alarm in EKEvent in calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, ekevent

when i create a new `EKEvent` for a calendar i notice that automatically add an alarm ad `9` of the event day, how i can set no `alarm`? i have tried in this way:

```
EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.titile = @"This is an event";
event.calendar = calendar;
event.alarms = nil; //in this way don't work...
```

but don't works, and in the calendar i see the alarm how u can see:

[image]

anyone knows how i can add EKEvent without alarm?

Comment: can u explain and write some code

Comment: Not sure what the problem was in this specific case, and it was asked a long time ago. Yet still there are problems and I found this question. This turned out to be the issue: I checked the events that I created on my phone using the calendar app on my Mac. That app shows a phantom 9:00 previous day alert that is not really there. Another bug, for instance, is that when you set an alert 24h prior to the event, it shows it as 48h before. I spent hours trying to fix a bug that does not exist in my app until I checked my events on the phone and in a browser where everything is correct.

Answer (score 1):

you should set an empty `NSArray` with no alarms, like this:

```
EKEvent *event = // whatever...
[event setAlarms:[NSArray array]];
```

Comment: then try again because it is the proper way. it is from a live application of mine.

Comment: i have tried again, and doens't work...i have also problem with the method predicateForEventsWithStartDate:endDate:calendars: that don't find me event...

Comment: can you describe what is wrong exactly? how do you mean in your original post the comment `// in this way don't work...`? what does it suppose to mean?

Comment: you need to know about this method `-predicateForEventsWithStartDate:endDate:calendars:`, it is working only 4 years interval from the start date. if your interval is wider than 4 years, e.g. 2000-2010 (10 years) you have to run the same method 3 times with intervals of 4-4-2 years for the proper result.

Comment: suppose to mean that, if i do setAlarms:nil or [event setAlarms:[NSArray array]]; when i check the added event in the calendar i can see that there an alarm...

Comment: yes i know how works the predicate: check my question for further detail...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812281/predicateforeventswithstartdateenddatecalendars-ekeventstore-doesnt-work

Comment: does anybody know why i'm getting an error with `EKErrorDomain Code=29` saying "Unable to modify alarms" (in italian..)? I didn't even find description for that error code.
This happens when setting alarms for an `EKEvent` with either .alarms property or addAlarm: selector.

Comment: @GianlucaP., you have to post this as a question with presenting more details about the circumstances.

Comment: sorry.. i've just found the problem after 4 hours searching... the problem was that i've set same endDate and startDate in the (all day) event, even if ios doesn't complain anymore it then forbids setting alarms programmatically. The answer is in this (off topic) question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7902447/1326326

Comment: still not working, posted new question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200413/cant-add-change-alarms-ekalarm-to-a-newly-created-ekevent-event

Answer (score 1):

I found that default alarm is set by Settings.app of Calendar settings.
I don't find a right way to setup an event without alarm if default alarm is set in settings.app.

Comment: This is the answer.  Launch Apple's Calendar app, then Preferences, Alerts and set the defaults to "None."

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the reason for why some of us gets an alarm when creating new EKEvents event though we have specified alarms off.
For me, and I'm guessing for most of you, the selected calendar is a google calendar.
Google calendar has a setting where it creates an alarm for every new event added.
To turn it off, log on to your google calendar on a web browser to turn it off.
I hope this will save some frustration!
Brgds,
Erik

Comment: Same thing for iOS and iCloud calendars.  See G-Power answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like only way to disable alarm is to create one in distant future using the following code

```
EKAlarm * alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
event.alarms = @[alarm];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The only way for me is removing it manually from the event just after creation:

```
private func CreateEntry(calendar : EKCalendar, date: Date, prop: String) {

    let event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)

    event.title = prop
    event.startDate = date
    event.endDate = date
    event.isAllDay = true
    event.notes = prop
    event.calendar = calendar //eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents

    if event.alarms != nil {
        for del in event.alarms! {
            event.removeAlarm(del)
        }
    }

    do {
        try eventStore.save(event, span: EKSpan.thisEvent, commit: true)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("failed to save event with error : \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved at my experience.
It depends, in the device, not in the simulator, by Settings/Mail,Contacts,Calendars/Default Alert Times/Events Setup.
If set to None you can add an alert or leave it as per the default, i.e. nil. It works.
If set to anything else, this overwrites any setup you make to the event alarm, nil included.